# Intervals of definition of ODE solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In this exercise I've to find the intervals in which solutions of differential equations (with separable variables) are defined. If I got it right, I must look at the constant solution of $y(x)$, then if I have to divide for $x$ or $y(x)$ I must impose them different from $0$

But in these equations for example

$1)$ $(1+x)y'=y+1$

$2)$ $y'=-\frac{x^{3}}{(y+1)^{2}}$

Do I have to impose in the first $x\neq -1$, $y\neq -1$ and in the second $y\neq -1$, $x\neq 0$ ?
Because the solutions

$1)$ $y(x)=C(x+1)-1$

$2)$ $y(x)= \sqrt[3]{C-\frac{3x^{2}}{4}} -1$

Are well defined for $x=0$ or $x=1$

Besides that in this other case

$3)$ $y'y(e^{x}+1)=e^{x}$

My book says that $y\neq 0$ but I don't understand why since to solve it is not necessary to divide for $y$

I have a similar problem with

$4)$ $y' y= x+1$

In this case if I substitute $y=0$ I find $x=-1$, again it is not necessary to divide for $y$ but I can rewrite the equation as $y'=\frac{x+1}{y}$ and then of course it must be $y\neq 0$.

I can't understand if the solution will meet the x axis or not

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's treat each question separately.

As to 1): you're absolutely right that the solution $y(x) = C(x+1) -1$ is well defined at $x = -1$, in which case $y = -1$. But that immediately shows the 'problem': there is no freedom to choose an initial condition for $x = -1$, since the free constant $C$ drops out. Another way of looking at this is that *every* solution, whatever initial condition you choose (generally at $t=0$, where $y(0) = C-1$), goes through the point $(x,y) = (-1,-1)$. In other words, the derivative $y'$ is not defined there. That's also clear from the ODE: you can choose any value you wish for $y'(-1)$, and the equation is still satisfied at $(x,y) = (-1,-1)$. So, in principle, you could construct a function by pasting together any solution of your choice for $x<-1$ and any other solution for $x > -1$, and that function (which then probably has a 'kink' at $(x,y) = (-1,-1)$, so is not differentiable there) would still satisfy the ODE *everywhere*. To conclude: you lose uniqueness. Of course, if you demand that your solution is differentiable *everywhere*, so in particular at $x = -1$, then the solution is unique.

At the second problem, for $x = 0$, it follows from the differential equation that $y'(0) = 0$ for every solution (you can also check this using the explicit solution formula you found). Is that a problem? Not really, it only tells you that every solution has an extremum at $x=0$. However, at $y=-1$, something does go wrong. From the differential equation, you see that at that point the derivative $y'$ is not defined. Moreover, you see that the closer you get to $y=-1$, the larger $y'$ gets. 
This can also be seen from the explicit solution form. Whatever initial condition you choose, i.e. whatever value of $C$ you put in, there are always two $x$-values where the square root vanishes, at $x_{\pm} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{3} C}$. For values larger than $x_+$ or smaller than $x_-$, the square root is not real (or doesn't exist anymore). So the solution only exists in the interval $(x_-,x_+)$, and at the end points of the interval we have $y = -1$. Other than in case 1), you can't continue after the singular point.

In the third problem, it's easy to see why $y$ can't be zero. Try it: if you substitute $y=0$ in the differential equation, you end up with
\begin{equation}
0 = e^x,
\end{equation}
and this equation cannot be satisfied for any $x$. Indeed, if you solve the equation, you'll see that no solution attains the value $y=0$ for any $x$, whatever the initial condition / choice of the free parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and clear answer! Regarding the third problem, is it the same for a similar equation like $y' y= x+1$ ? In this case for $y=0$ I find $x=-1$ so actually some solutions will meet the $x$ axis? Because I can rewrite the equation as $y'=\frac{x+1}{y}$ and then of course it must be $y\neq 0$ I'm quite confused about it

Comment: There something else is going on: maybe it's a good idea to include this case in your question, such that I can edit my answer.